# App rerendering without the use of useEffect Hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, rerender

I am learning useEffect Hook in React and I have a question based on its usage.

Following is the code, which is still working fine as expected without the use of `useEffect` Hook.

My question is - if this code is working is it advisable to go ahead without adding `useEffect` in code or I am missing some concept here.
I know there are other lifecycle methods that can be mimic in functional component using `useEffect` hook, but for small cases like this is it advisable to take this approach ?

**Code -**

```
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState(null);
  const [num, setNum] = useState(2);
  // useEffect(() => {
  fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${num}`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((response) => {
      const { title } = response;
      setTitle(title);
    });
  // }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>useEffect Example</h1>
      <pre>{title}</pre>

      <button onClick={() => setNum(num + 1)}>Increment</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be extremely advisable to use `useEffect` here. If your `App` component re-renders for any reason, then your fetch logic will execute again.

When you use `useEffect` with a dependency array, you ensure that the effect within `useEffect` is only executed when that dependency changes.

```
 useEffect(() => {
  fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${num}`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((response) => {
      const { title } = response;
      setTitle(title);
    });
   }, [num]);
```

Comment: I get it.. in case if API needs to be called at once I can use the empty array signature in useEffect but since I need to update the app whenever number changes ..this app is re rendering and working correctly, so my original question is that is it ok to take the approach without useEffect if this is the case ?

Comment: @Nesh Since you wish to use `num` here, I'd suggest adding `num` to your dependency array in `useEffect` so that the fetch call is only made when `num` changes. I've updated my example to reflect this.

Comment: Another reason to use `useEffect` here is to create a mounted guard,  if the `fetch` takes a while and the component is unmounted before it completes you will get an error in the console calling setState on an unmounted component.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with this is that each time the component executes its code is going to fetch the API and that is not a thing that you may want.

Probably in this example you will not see any mayor difference (as the way that the code is working) but as soon as you add this component to a more complex tree it will start to behave unexpectedly.

Answer (score 0):

You should use useEffect here.
The reason is that without it you will be calling fetch() on every rerender which is most likely not the thing you want to do.

In this case title is probably a string and does not change so it will not break, but in most cases this would be a dead loop. I’m also pretty sure that for every click you are now doing two fetch() calls - one after increment, and one with the same data after updating title.

This will also be a problem if you add any other unrelated state to your component, because you will start spamming fetch() with unchanged data.